# How do i make delete button work?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to make a delete button but it doesn't work.

```
$interogare = "SELECT * FROM comments JOIN users ON users.user_id = comments.user_id WHERE movie_id='$movie_id' ORDER BY date_posted DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $interogare) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
    while($rand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 
         echo '<a href="film.php?com='.$rand['comment_id'].'">Delete</a>';

         if(isset($_GET['com'])) {

            $haidi = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['com']);
            $sql_del = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE comment_id = '$haidi'";
            mysqli_query($dbc,$sql_del);
            header('location: film.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'');
            exit();
         }

     }
```

When i click the delete link it takes me to

> film.php?com='.$rand['comment_id'].'

page but nothing happens,it should delete my comment and take me back to the page where the comment was.Can someone please help me figure this out ?

Comment: What is the url of film.php and where is the code of film.php

Comment: this code is in film.php

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string need 2 parameter. You are passing only one. you need to pass connection link along with string. Please check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: i have written $haidi = $_GET['com']; and it still doesn't work and neither  $haidi = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['com']);

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
<?php
$query = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM comments 
        JOIN users ON users.user_id = comments.user_id 
        WHERE movie_id=" . $movie_id  . " 
        ORDER BY date_posted DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

if (isset($_GET)) {
    $getData = $_GET;
}

while ($rand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<a href="film.php?com=' . $rand['comment_id'] . '">Delete</a>';

    if (isset($getData) && $getData['com']) {

        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $getData['com']);

        $query = "
            DELETE FROM comments 
            WHERE comment_id=" . $id;

        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

        if($result)
        {
            header('location: film.php?id=' . $id . '');
        }
        exit();
    }
}
```

i would rather grab the post once, and then make sure we are passing the same object around, so i set GET to a var.  then, i didnt like the way the ids were being set in the query, because it wasnt as easy to see.  then i got down to the way you were creating the header, and it looked like you were passing the id from some GET data, instead of the id you just extracted and set to a varibale, see above..., or was that your intention to use $_GET['id'] for that actually instead?

also, you might need to pass your data link in the mysqli_real_escape_string() method

Comment: do you see any new problems with it, or does it give you same as you had before?

Comment: the same as before,it takes me to film.php?com=5(5 is the comment id ) and nothing happens then .